# Warning in @implementation method in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, implementation

How to remove the warnings `protocol not implemented` in iOS?

[image]

Thanks..

Comment: You implement them, since the warning is there because the methods are mandatory. If the where `@optional` you do not have to implement them.

Comment: Maybe you should implement the methods? Or say that you class is not compliant with the protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning tells you that you conform to a protocol, but didn't fully implement it in the corresponding class.

You can use the `@optional` flag to make a protocol method optional. But then you should check, in the class, that has the protocol, if the conforming class also implemented the method.

```
@protocol NSAnyClassDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)thisMethodIsRequired;

@optional
- (void)thisAndFollowingMethodsAreOptional;
- (void)optionalMethod;

@required
- (void)thisAndFollowingMethodsAreRequired;
- (void)requiredMethod;

@end
```

Tip:

```
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(optionalMethod)]) {
    [_delegate optionalMethod];
}
```